# why the ending g keyword in this sed substitute command is not matching all the occurrences?

Tags: sed

I want to replace one string by another in multiple contexts.

I wrote a regexp that matches every context, then wrote the substitution, then added the `g` keyword to make sure all the occurrences of the same line get substituted.

This is an example of file (`test.txt`) I attempt to translate:

```
"keyword" "tremor"
000,tremor
tremor
word word tremor word
word tremor word tremor word tremor
// tremor
//tremor
tremor
    qer_editorImage tremor
    diffuseMap  tremor
    aniMap tremor tremor tremor tremor
```

This is the sed (`test.sed`) file I wrote:

```
s#\(^\|//\|[," \t]\)tremor\([" \t]\|$\)#\1niveus\2#gI
```

This is the way I run sed:

```
sed -f test.sed test.txt
```

This is what I expect for the `aniMap` line:

```
    aniMap niveus niveus niveus niveus
```

This is what I get instead:

```
    aniMap niveus tremor niveus tremor
```

Edit: I suppose it is related to the fact the next occurrence is part of the precedent one being replaced, if yes, how to workaround this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `\b` for word boundaries.

`sed -E 's/\bniveus\b/tremor/g'`

You don't have to worry about the `\b` in the replacement... it's a zero-length match like `^` for start of pattern space and `$` for end.

And if you're worried about substrings, it *won't* replace `niveusxxx` with `tremorxxx`, which I think is point of where you were headed.

Comment: So, while not answering the question itself (what @jhnc did), it fullfilled to my need!
It's too bad I can't pick the two answers as the “_selected_” ones. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed, the end of your regex matches the start of the next occurrence.

If we delimit the first match with square brackets:

```
    aniMap[ tremor ]tremor tremor tremor
```

it should be clear that the second occurrence of "tremor" does not match the regexp. It is not possible in general to create a regexp that does not have this problem.

A simple workaround is to not use /g but instead to loop the command until it fails:

```
:x
s#\(^\|//\|[," \t]\)tremor\([" \t]\|$\)#\1niveus\2#I
tx
```

(It is more efficient to retain the /g but if you leave it off the replacements will happen from left to right)

Comment: That's good to know! I guess I can put any line I want between `:x` and `tx`?

Only two loops are needed to match `aniMap[ tremor ]tremor[ tremor ]tremor`
then `aniMap niveus[ tremor ]niveus[ tremor]`, so it may be acceptable to loop.

Comment: Additional note because I can't edit my previous comment: it only run twice when using both the loop **and `/g`**

So, this works too! While @stevesliva's solution is more elegant for my real need, thank you to have taught me something I'm sure I will reuse another time. That was the answer I was looking for as I also asked this question because I wanted to understand what was going on, not only because I needed a solution. :-)

Comment: @ThomasDebesse Upvoting is almost as valuable rep-wise as getting an answer accepted, so swing back when/if you can do that.   The hover text is "this answer is useful," so it's appropriate.

Comment: yep, but I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet :-)